# Full Calendar change view based on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using Full Calendar for my web-app. When viewing on a computer, I want it to display the entire month (dayGridMonth). But when viewing on a mobile device, I want it to display just the day (dayGridDay).

What about my code is not allowing this to happen?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
   var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      events: 'fetchSchedule.php',
      selectable: false,
   });

   $(window).resize(function() {
      if(window.innerWidth < 800){
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'dayGridDay');
      } else {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'dayGridMonth');
      }
   });

   calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors reported (as it relates to javascript)?

Comment: schedule.php:64 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
    at schedule.php:64:20
    at dispatch (jquery.js:5429:27)
    at elemData.handle (jquery.js:5233:28)
    at Object._triggerWindowEvent (helpers.js:177:14)
    at eval (helpers.js:516:14)
schedule.php:62 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
    at schedule.php:62:20
    at dispatch (jquery.js:5429:27)
    at elemData.handle (jquery.js:5233:28)

Comment: Check your import and don’t load jquery twice.

Comment: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar` is fullCalendar v3 syntax (when it was implemented as a jQuery plugin), but the rest of your code uses the syntax of v4 and above, which is _not_ a jQuery implementation. I guess you've  just copied some old code from the internet without checking the current documentation to see if it makes sense. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-changeView for details and current syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Use [windowResize](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/windowResize) trigger.

```
function( arg: { view } )
```

The calendar has automatically adapted to the new size when windowResize is triggered.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    windowResize: (arg) => { // your code}
  });
```

Comment: So put my entire code within the curly brackets after "... (ago => { "